# How to add R Package Example showing Shiny App?

Tags: r, shiny

I am making a package in R. One of the functions has a shiny app:

```
shinyAppFunction(interval_data)
```

Now, I made an example section as:

```
#' @examples 
#' data(interval_data)
#' shinyAppFunction(interval_data)
```

Now, when I run R CMD check and it gets to

```
checking examples ...
```

This line never terminates (i.e. it takes an infinite amount of time, so the package is never completely checked).

I am guessing it is because the shinyAppFunction is called, it works correctly, but it is never quit out of the session. So it just stays up indefinitely, and the "checking examples..." therefore never finishes. How can I fix this, to show the example but also ensure that the example passes the CMD check?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap the shiny app code inside an `if (interactive()) {` block, so that it will only run when in an interactive mode.

```
#' @examples 
#' if (interactive()) {
#'   data(interval_data)
#'   shinyAppFunction(interval_data)
#' }
```

[Here's an example usage of that in my own code](https://github.com/daattali/shinyjs/blob/f5f57c6c2098d712c0e2cae8ba6c24db52d50fbe/R/onevent.R#L51)